# Python: Appending empty list with list overwrites previously added list

Tags: python

I am trying to add all processed lists (removed empty list items, removed all `\n` and `\r` etc.) to empty list called `allOrders`. Problem is that after the code is executed `allOrders` contains only the list that was appended as the last one.

```py
import os

if orderFilesListCount >= 1:
    for singleOrderFile in orderFilesList:                       # does the following to all Orders in OrderFileList
        orderContents = list()                                   # creates empty list 
        dataRemoveSpaces = list()                                # creates empty list 
        allOrders = list()                                       # creates empty list
        f = open(os.path.join(directory, singleOrderFile), "rb") # opens each order file 
        data = f.read().decode("utf16")                          # decodes data from file
        dataRemoveLine = data.rstrip().split('\n')               # removes new lines
        dataRemoveTabs = [s.strip('\r') for s in dataRemoveLine] # removes all /r from list items
        dataRemoveEmpty = list(filter(None, dataRemoveTabs))     # removes all empty list items
        for element in dataRemoveEmpty:                          # following code trimms all elements in list
            element = element.strip()
            dataRemoveSpaces.append(element)                     # add trimmed elements back to list
        print(dataRemoveSpaces)                                  # my verification if the list was sucessfuly processed
        allOrders.append(dataRemoveSpaces)                       # appends allOrders list with processed list
```

I know for a fact that it is not the problem with code that "processes" every individual list (thanks to last `print` - it looks exactly as it should).

What is the issue here? I've seen couple threads that deal with similar problems but can't able to apply their solutions to mine.

Comment: You really need to use functions. You have data definition, filesystem IO, processing, output etc all in one function. Bound to make errors like this. Separate your code out.

Answer (score 2):

put line:

```
allOrders = list()#creates empty list
```

out of the for loop, because every step you iterate you are creating an empty list, because of that you have just last list

Answer (score 1):

You re-create `allOrders` each iteration:

`allOrders = list()#creates empty list`

So you erase it. Move this line out of the loop, in if-statement:

```
if orderFilesListCount >= 1:
    allOrders = list()  # <------------------- HERE
    for singleOrderFile in orderFilesList:
```

Or even out the if-statement:

```
allOrders = list()  # <------------------- HERE
if orderFilesListCount >= 1:
    for singleOrderFile in orderFilesList:
```

So you will not erase it constantly.